# How can global variables be used in bvp4c in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, variables, global-variables, global, ode

When the boundary value problem and the boundary conditions are written in different files and called in the function bvp4c, it seems that variables named in these external files are not recognized.

To be more specific, let me give as an example the problem I'm working with right now. The main file is

```
clearvars
% Creating a grid of x values for MATLAB to solve on and an initial guess for y(x) and y'(x)
solinit=bvpinit(linspace(0,1,100),[1 0]);    % solinit = bvpinit(x,yinit) forms the initial guess for a boundary value problem solver.
solution=bvp4c(@bvp,@bc,solinit);
plot(solution.x,solution.y);
```

The boundary value probem (bvp.m) is

```
% Diff*y''+2*i*Epsilon*y=0
% Diff*y2'+2*i*Epsilon*y1=0, y2=y1'
% y1'=                      y2
% y2'=-2*i*Epsilon/Diff*y1
function yprime=bvp(t,y)
% Treating y1,y2 as components of y, [y1,y2], yprime as their derivative, [y1',y2']
yprime=[y(2);-2*i*Epsilon/Diff*y(1)];
```

and the boundary conditions (bc.m) are given by

```
% Boundary conditions
function res=bc(y0,y1)
% Return the residue
res=[-Ratio*y0(2)-y1(1);Ratio*y1(2)-y0(1)];   % The vectors y0 and y1 are the solutions at x=0 and x=1
```

When replacing the variables `Diff`, `Epsilon` and `Ratio` by 1, 3 and 100 respectively, there is a nice solution given in a graph.

When writing this out with the variables, even when adding

```
global Diff Epsilon Ratio
```

to the main file, or to all files, I get errors, such as

> Undefined function or variable 'Epsilon'.

The preferable way of handling the variables would be to define them once, in the main file. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: "When replacing the variables"?  [`bvp4c`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bvp4c.html) is a numerical solver.  All parameters must have a definition for the solver to work.  It reads as though you are using [`global`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html?refresh=true) correctly; although you may want to look at a [more elegant way](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html) of sharing data among functions.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the main function, this command should be added in 'bc' and 'bvp' functions too

global Diff Epsilon Ratio